Folder not being added on run Visual Studio
Im trying to load folder with .bat files, i tried putting as resource, as copy always, etc, and when i go on bin, there is no folder i have on explorer, and yes it is in project implemented yet.
i tried putting as resource, as copy always, etc, and when i go on bin, there is no folder i have on explorer, and yes it is in project implemented yet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you offer more information? like what your specific steps and some picture.
